# HTML5 video player doesn't show the controls bar in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack

I am using HTML5 video tag as below-

```
<video id="videoPlayerId" controls="controls" />
<button onclick="play()"> Play </button>
```

And with Javascript-

```
let player = document.getElementById("videoPlayerId")
this.setAttribute('src', 'https://something.com/srcurl.mp4')
player.preload = 'metadata'
function play () {
  player.play()
}
```

On localhost, the video shows controls bar properly but when the same code is uploaded to the LIVE site, the video doesn't show the control bar in Chrome but control bar looks fine in Firefox. So, what could possibly be going wrong on LIVE site causing Chrome to not display the Controls bar?

Also, when I right click on the video on LIVE site in Chrome, it shows "tick mark" next to "Show Control" option but the bar still doesn't show up.

I have also done research on internet and couldn't find any solution so far. There is only once place where the same problem has been reported on Chrome Developer help centre- https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/18545176?hl=en but unfortunately, there has been no response from Chrome team as well.

Further updates, I noticed that the video bar doesn't show only in Vue JS production mode, the production build is generated by WebPack. However it works fine in Development mode. Does this ring bells in anyone's mind?

Please help! Very thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified on separate machines/installations of Chrome?

Comment: And -- I've had issues with Chrome and Video if you don't include `muted=""` inside the `<video>` tag

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem for us on jsfiddle.net?